# SQL Join two tables but only where certain conditions exist explicitly

Tags: sql, join

For some reason I cannot get my head wrapped around this. I have two tables and I need to return just one field from one of them when all of the dependent rows in the joined table meet certain criteria. A simplified version of tables:

```
COMPONENT:

RegionAcronym

OfficeCode


OFFICE:

OfficeCode

LimitSwitch

CloseDate
```

What I need is to get the RegionAcronym from COMPONENT when every OfficeCode with that RegionAcronym has the LimitSwitch set to 'Y' and CloseDate of NULL or > CURRENT_DATE in OFFICE. The problem I run in to is that there are OfficeCode's in the COMPONENT table that do not have entries in the OFFICE table.

I tried this:

```
SELECT c.RegionAcronym FROM cmpnt c 
LEFT JOIN Office o
ON o.OfficeCode = c.OfficeCode AND o.LimitSwitch = 'Y' 
AND (o.CloseDate =  NULL or o.CloseDate > CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY c.RegionAcronym
HAVING COUNT(o.OfficeCode) = COUNT(c.OfficeCode)
```

This does not return the right acronyms. I believe it is not excluding OfficeCodes in the COMPONENT table when there are no records in OFFICE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: @balaji, it is DB2 but is going through a JPA entity manager, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then `NOT EXISTS` seems like a good way to express this:

```
SELECT c.RegionAcronym
FROM cmpnt c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Office o
                  WHERE o.OfficeCode = c.OfficeCode AND
                        NOT (o.LimitSwitch = 'Y' AND
                             (o.CloseDate IS NULL OR o.CLoseDate > CURRENT_DATE)
                            )
                 )
```

In terms of performance, this does not require aggregation.

Comment: SELECT 1? I am confused.

Comment: With just a small bit of testing, I believe this is the answer! Will mark it as the best answer once I fully test it in my code.

Answer (score 2):

To do a join of tables you set your conditions for joining rows in your ON clause as you have done.

The problem with the code you posted is that you cannot compare columns to NULL with the = operator, you must use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL so change

```
AND (o.CloseDate =  NULL or o.CloseDate > CURRENT_DATE
```

to

```
AND (o.CloseDate IS NULL or o.CloseDate > CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Sorry, was typing from memory, it is in there as IS NULL, still no bueno.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER, then change CURRENT_DATE to `GETDATE()`

```
SELECT c.RegionAcronym FROM cmpnt c 
LEFT JOIN Office o
ON o.OfficeCode = c.OfficeCode
WHERE NOT (o.LimitSwitch = 'Y' 
            AND (o.CloseDate IS NULL or o.CloseDate > CURRENT_DATE))
GROUP BY c.RegionAcronym
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the fact that I don't want the Acronym if anything in OFFICE has LimitSwitch = 'N'

Comment: @ssgtob1 can elobrate a bit?

Comment: I only need the RegionAcronyms from component when all of the OFFICEs meet that criteria, if any of them are set to 'N' I don't want the acronym.